# How to add 5 minutes to a date stored as a string 'YYYYMMDDHHMM'

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime-format

I have a date format of '201906192359' stored as a string but I need to add 5 minutes to it being conscious of hour or date changes. 
As a result I've converted the above into a datetime to add the 5 minutes but I now need to revert it back into YYYYMMDDHHMM.

```
DECLARE @test varchar(50);
SET @test = '201906192359';

PRINT @test;

set @test = convert(datetime,substring(@test,1,8)) +
DATEADD(hh,0+substring(@test,9,2),0) +
DATEADD(mi,5+SUBSTRING(@test,11,2),0) 

PRINT @test;
```

The examples I've seen incorporate seconds and I haven't been able to adjust my code to match. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way.

```
 SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(16),DATEADD(mi,5,STUFF(STUFF(@test,11,0,':'),9,0,' ')),120),'-',''),' ',''),':','');
```

I'm sure that someone will recommend the following if you're using SQL Server 2012 or above:

```
 SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(mi,5,STUFF(STUFF(@test,11,0,':'),9,0,' ')), 'yyyyMMddHHmm')
```

While the latter looks pretty slick, the FORMAT function makes it comparatively horribly slow so I recommend never (and I don't use that word often) using the FORMAT function.

Answer (score 1):

You should fix your data!  Don't store date/time values in strings.  You can convert the value to a `datetime` using:

```
select (convert(datetime, left(test, 8)) +
        convert(datetime, timefromparts(substring(test, 9, 2), right(test, 2), 0, 0, 0))
       )
from (values ('201906192359')) v(test);
```

You can then add 5 minutes using `dateadd()`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon but the database is a suppliers and we have no say in their format. Your solution delivers the same results as my original code. Where I'm stuck is converting the datetime back into YYYYMMDDHHMM.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: So your saying the problem isn't adding 5 minutes, but it's creating a `varchar` in the format `yyyyMMddhhmmss`? That's a very different question, @Scotty .